# INDIRECT function error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have the following formula which has been returning `#REF!` error for a long time regardless of how I redesign it. The value on C1 is the name of a tab which has data on the referenced cells:

```
Aug 2012
```

This part of the formula returns the correct numerical value:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & C1 & "'" & "!A502'")
```

but this formula gives the error:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'" & C1 & "'" & "!A502:'" & C1 & "'" & "!A503"))
```

Any help on where I am making a mistake please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula you have there would be:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!A502:A503"))
```

I have tested this and confirmed that it works when C1 says "Sheet 2" and I have another sheet named "Sheet 2".

Two things I've changed:

First - you referenced it so that it would repeat the sheet name for the first cell listed in the range (A502) as well as the second cell (A503). But if you manually select A502:A503 in an excel formula, you can see that it takes the form: 'Sheet Name'!A502:A503.

I have also simplified the formula so that the "'" is in the same string as the "!". However it would have worked without this change.

The key to dynamically creating formulas like this (either using INDIRECT or in VBA) is to make sure you actually go back to Excel and try typing it out manually - what does Excel take as an acceptable formula? Also - if you want to see why a formula isn't working, go to the Formulas ribbon, and click 'evaluate formula'. This will let you go step by step through the formula as it simplifies. If you did that here it would have shown you what the final reference was that was created by your formula, and you could have compared that with your own manually created version.

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you for the answer and lengthy explanation! Appreciate your time.